# Rust vs. C: Why would a Rust reference to the characters in a String all show the same memory address?

Tags: c, pointers, rust

I'm trying to understand Rust's pointer/reference system compared to C. I've included *roughly* equivalent Rust and C code and their outputs. The code aims to declare a "string", declare a pointer to the first element/character of the string and then for each element:

1. Print the raw pointer (memory address)
2. Print the character itself (by dereferencing pointer)
3. Print the memory address again (by referencing the value obtained from step 2)

**All steps work as I expect in C, however step 3 does not work as expected in Rust. How can I operate unsafe pointer arithmetic like this in Rust? (i.e. create pointer; deref; ref the deref)**

**Rust src**

```
fn main() {
    //Init String, pointer and get String length for iterator
    let my_str = String::from("York");
    let my_str_ptr: *const u8 = my_str.as_ptr();
    println!("Original string: {my_str}");

    for i in 0..my_str.len() {
        unsafe {
            //Offset pointer by i
            let chr_ptr: *const u8 = my_str_ptr.offset(i as isize);
            let chr: char = *chr_ptr as char;

            println!("Deref raw pointer: {chr}");
            println!("Raw pointer:       {chr_ptr:p}");
            println!("Ref to value:      {:p}", &chr);
        }
    }
}
```

**Rust output:**

```
Original string: York
Deref raw pointer: Y
Raw pointer:       0x561e134b8ba0
Ref to value:      0x7ffd962f665c
Deref raw pointer: o
Raw pointer:       0x561e134b8ba1
Ref to value:      0x7ffd962f665c
Deref raw pointer: r
Raw pointer:       0x561e134b8ba2
Ref to value:      0x7ffd962f665c
Deref raw pointer: k
Raw pointer:       0x561e134b8ba3
Ref to value:      0x7ffd962f665c
```

**C source:**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char *my_str = "York";
    char *my_str_ptr = my_str;
    printf("Original string: %s\n", my_str);

    while (*my_str_ptr != '\0') {
        printf("Deref raw pointer: %p\n", my_str_ptr);
        printf("Raw pointer:       %c\n", *my_str_ptr);
        printf("Ref to value:      %p\n\n", &(*my_str_ptr));
        my_str_ptr++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**C output:**

```
Original string: York
Deref raw pointer: 0x559af0d44004
Raw pointer:       Y
Ref to value:      0x559af0d44004
Deref raw pointer: 0x559af0d44005
Raw pointer:       o
Ref to value:      0x559af0d44005
Deref raw pointer: 0x559af0d44006
Raw pointer:       r
Ref to value:      0x559af0d44006
Deref raw pointer: 0x559af0d44007
Raw pointer:       k
Ref to value:      0x559af0d44007
```

As can be seen plainly in this extremely simple example, it is straightforward to layer ref/deref operators in C such that values and their references can be obtained, however this does not appear to be the case for chars in rust.

I have a suspicion it is caused by Rust's print formatter and that the issue has nothing to do with the way in which Rust implements pointers, values and addresses.

Comment: `&chr` is a reference to the actual variable `chr` on the stack, so it seems the compiler is reusing the same stack memory for the same variable each time. Note it's very different from something like `&(*my_str_pointer)` which you're using in C, or in other words your C and Rust do completely different things. `chr` is a copy of the character not a pointer to the character.

Comment: In Rust you're printing the address of the local variable `chr`. In C you're printing the address of the character in the string. The equivalent C code would be: `char chr = *my_str_ptr;` and then print `&chr`.

Comment: An equivalent Rust code would look something like [this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=6c90fbf3766c76f0930787e9384fbd72) (I even included your probably typod swap of ptr vs dereferenced).

Comment: @cafce25 that’s the bingo. Thanks. Going round in circles on this one for a few hours (needed sleep). Obvious when you put your code on playground. I had considered char being local (with compiler reusing same stack addr) but discounted it some time ago. My errors were not considering scope properly and not utilising with the “global” string ptr to achieve objective.

Comment: Go ahead and post an answer formally if you wish. If not, I’ll give it some time, clean up my question a little bit and post your answer pretty much verbatim, just with a bit more verbosity. Thx again.

Comment: These are _**not**_ equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

The below answer and code reflects the comments made by cafce25, which answered my original question and addressed my confusion.

The C and Rust code is not equivalent. Whereas the C code works directly on a globally/main() defined variable within the iteration block, the Rust code creates a new locally scoped char each iteration, which prints correctly.

However when it comes to printing the memory address of the individual char - the output is showing the address of the locally scoped char that is created anew each time the for loop iterates; it just happens to be the case that the compiler reuses the same stack address to store the char.

**Fixed Rust Code:**

```
fn main() {
    let my_str = "York";
    println!("Original string: {}\n", my_str);

    //Declared mutable to allow iteration over elements
    let mut my_str_ptr = my_str.as_ptr();

    for _ in 0..my_str.len() {
        unsafe {
            println!("Pointer: {:p}", my_str_ptr);
            //Dereference my_str not a new local char
            println!("Deref pointer: {}", *my_str_ptr as char);
            //Reference dereferenced pointer to my_str, not new char
            println!("Ref derefed pointer: {:p}\n", &*my_str_ptr);
            my_str_ptr = my_str_ptr.offset(1);
        }
    }
}
```

**Fixed Rust program output:**

```
Original string: York

Pointer: 0x55a9f9d0705b
Deref pointer: Y
Ref derefed pointer: 0x55a9f9d0705b

Pointer: 0x55a9f9d0705c
Deref pointer: o
Ref derefed pointer: 0x55a9f9d0705c

Pointer: 0x55a9f9d0705d
Deref pointer: r
Ref derefed pointer: 0x55a9f9d0705d

Pointer: 0x55a9f9d0705e
Deref pointer: k
Ref derefed pointer: 0x55a9f9d0705e
```